# How to add text to icons in ActionBar?

Tags: android

Is that possible to define a text which to be shown in ActionBar along with icon?

[image]

Is that a text or just an image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` to show the menu title along with the icon.

Comment: Hi This never works for me, i'm loading in Galaxy nexus and even using "always|withText" it only ever shows the text if in landscape mode. even though i am testing with just a single item and there is a entire title bar of unused space. Any ideas?

Comment: seems it doesn't work in ICS+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511348/title-for-icon-in-actionbar-is-not-shown

Comment: @wired00: `showAsAction` is a hint, not a command. Android will interpret that hint how it wants based on screen size and orientation.