# Title for icon in actionbar is not shown

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, title

Hi I want to add a icon with title to my actionbar, but only the icon is shown. I created this item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_save"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:title="@string/menu_save"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

Anyone a idea? I also changed `ifRoom` to `always` but still the same problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That occurs in ICS, right? This appears to be a bug in ICS

> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30180

Comment: Correct, and as described in the link if i switch to landscape the title is shown... damn that sucks...

Comment: Discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282122/android-4-0-text-on-the-action-bar-never-shows