# Set android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to set the flags as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189465/how-to-add-text-to-icons-in-actionbar) `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` programmatically?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For each `MenuItem`, do the following:

```
myMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

Comment: I try `myMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);` on kotlin  but it didnt work, it only allow to input with one value type, is there any other way?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to set these properties at run time then you need to do so on the `MenuItem`, not the `ActionBar`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
    item.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

Comment: I believe that should be `(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT)`, flag-style.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions(int)), I don't think this should work, since `setDisplayOptions()` needs the ActionBar `DISPLAY_` constants Although, some constants [*do* overlap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS).