# SubMenu showAsAction when added at runtime

Tags: android, runtime, submenu

I'm adding a SubMenu at runtime and everything works great.
I just have a problem: how to `set showAsAction="always"` on a runtime-added SubMenu?
There is no method to achieve that and if don't set it I can't find any way to have it shown in the Action Bar.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138305/set-androidshowasaction-ifroomwithtext-programmatically

Comment: no.. same as one of the answers below i'm trying to set showAsAction to a SubMenu not to a MenuItem.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this is too late or not, but SubMenu has as function called getItem() which returns a MenuItem. You can then get this MenuItem, and call setShowAsAction() afterwards. Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Call `yourSubMenu.getItem()`. This give you MenuItem that represent the SubMenu.

Answer (score 0):

If im right then 
`MenuItem = item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);`

Comment: yeah i thought that but SubMenu is not a MenuItem, isn't it? In your answer you're calling setShowAsAction on a MenuItem not on a SubMenu

Comment: How can I try it? I have `SubMenu menu;` from here how should I call your  `MenuItem.setShowAsAction()`? Do you mean calling it on one of the child items of my SubMenu?