# Why ActionbarSharelock shows only overflow icon even there are room

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, optionmenu

I am stuck with Menu item visibility in ABS even there are room in header. Thing is I have test in different size of device but in each case i am able to see only one and that is Overflow menu.

I am using `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to manage my menu as dynamically and that is working perfectly.(but don't know may be this issue is occur bye `onPrepareOptionsMenu` or some other reason).

**View Difference:** 
[image]
[image]

**First Approach** I have create menu programmatically and set that visibility using [setShowAsAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction%28int%29). Somewhere i have found [setShowAsActionflag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsActionFlags%28int%29) also and i have try that also. But in that case i am not able to see Overflow menu in `small screen 320*480`. So, That is my issue in programmatically approach.

Here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
    // TO Remove older menu otherwise that will apped menu each time.
    menu.clear();

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SEARCH, Menu.NONE, "Search").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SETTING, Menu.NONE, "Settings").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_settings)
        .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    if (is_session_exist == 1) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CHANGE_LOGIN, Menu.NONE, "Change Login").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_add_person)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_LOGOUT, Menu.NONE, "Logout").setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_clear)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);


    } else {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_LOGIN, Menu.NONE, "Login").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_add_person)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Second Approach** I have create menu using XML folder and set all property in separate file. Now i am inflecting that menu in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` but in that case i am only able to see overflow icon in any density screen even i have set the  `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"`

Here is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_search"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Search"
                android:visible="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_login"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Login"
                android:visible="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_change_login"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Change Login"
                android:visible="false"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_setting"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Setting"
                android:visible="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_clear"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Logout"
                android:visible="false"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I am changing menu item in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` using `setVisible(false/true);`

Here some helpful link which i have refer already but issue is not solve yet.

[Set android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138305/set-androidshowasaction-ifroomwithtext-programmatically)

[How to add text to icons in ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189465/how-to-add-text-to-icons-in-actionbar)

I don't know why i am getting this issue .Your help and effort will definitely appreciate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, for devices with screen resolution 320*480 you wont get an overflow icon, instead on click of menu button of the device you can get the rest menu items as below image:

[image]

Comment: Grate Catch. I never notice that thing.Thanks :) At least my java coding works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are having two `menu` (1) nested

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item..
          ">
        <menu>
```

It should all be single menu with the overflow menu item removed.. it is shown automatically.

> Updated menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_search"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Search"
                android:visible="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_login"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Login"
                android:visible="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_change_login"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Change Login"
                android:visible="false"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_setting"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Setting"
                android:visible="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_clear"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Logout"
                android:visible="false"/>
     </menu>
```

Comment: if i remove that , then i am getting issue of first approach.